# PDFKit not generating correct PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdfkit

I installed PDFKit and wkhtmltopdf.

In one action I render a simple html like:

```
<html><body><h1>Hello Internet!</h1></body></html>
```

When I run my action with .pdf extension it generates a wrong pdf file. Debugging PDFKit I got to these lines:

```
result = IO.popen(invoke, "w+") do |pdf|
  pdf.puts(@source.to_s) if @source.html?
  pdf.close_write
  pdf.gets(nil)
end
```

Well, this is where my PDF is generated, it uses a command line no wkhtmltopdf and my html as input.

Using rdebug I found that the value for invoke is:

```
"c:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe" "--margin-right" "0.75in" "--page-size" "Letter" "--margin-top" "0.75in" "--margin-bottom" "0.75in" "--encoding" "UTF-8" "--margin-left" "0.75in" "--quiet" "-" "-"
```

And @source.to_s is

```
<html><body><h1>Hello Internet!</h1></body></html>
```

Ok, so I tried to run the command by hand like this:

```
"c:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe" "--margin-right" "0.75in" "--page-size" "Letter" "--margin-top" "0.75in" "--margin-bottom" "0.75in" "--encoding" "UTF-8" "--margin-left" "0.75in" "--quiet" "-" "-" < c:\hello_internet.html > correct.pdf
```

Obviously in hello_internet there is the content of @source.to_s

Running it results in the correct pdf being generated.

The correct pdf generated is [here](http://www.acras.com.br/downloads/correct.pdf) and the wrong is [here](http://www.acras.com.br/downloads/wrong.pdf).

I have no idea what can be wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I got it wrong! Are you trying to use pdfkit to generate a pdf from HTML source **without** using wkhtmltopdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple and is object of a [pull request](https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit/pull/80) by bxu689 at PDFKits Github.